# NextJS frontend throws ECONNREFUSED when connecting to strapi backend in docker container

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker-compose, next.js

I have 2 frontend applications using NextJS and a backend using strapi/node. Trying to get all of them set up with separate docker compose builds in development. There's also a third project which is a shared react app that both nextjs projects rely on for components.

All set up with yarn workspaces.

Backend is spun up on localhost, listening on port 1337, no issues there, here's the docker-compose:

```
services:
  database:
    image: "postgres" 
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
      - ./database/init_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql # create user, database and data when initializing container
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - shared

  blog-server:
    container_name: backend
    build: 
      context: blog-server/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=database
      - DATABASE_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=blog_backend
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
      - DATABASE_NAME=blog
      - DATABASE_SSL=false
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./blog-server:/app # this should use your local files for live reloading
      - backend_node_modules:/app/node_modules # the node_modules folder causes a problem when it's copied over, so we mount it to a volume on it's own
      - backend_uploads:/app/public/uploads
    networks:
      - shared

networks:
  shared:
    external: true

volumes:
  database-data: {}
  backend_node_modules: {}
  backend_uploads: {}
```

If I run either of the frontends without docker just using 'yarn dev' they both work fine. What I'm trying to achieve is to have 'ev-site' hosted at "/" and 'blog' hosted at "/blog". To do that, I'm composing the frontends with an nginx container. Here's the docker-compose for the frontend:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .env:/app/blog/.env.local
      - .env:/app/ev-site/.env.local
      - ./blog:/app/blog
      - ./ev-site:/app/ev-site
      - ./library:/app/library
      - frontend_node_modules:/app/node_modules # the node_modules folder causes a problem when it's copied over, so we mount it to a volume on it's own
      - blog_node_modules:/app/blog/node_modules
      - evsite_node_modules:/app/ev-site/node_modules
      - library_node_modules:/app/library/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
      - "3002:3002"
    networks:
      - shared

  nginx:
    container_name: frontend-nginx
    build:
      context: nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - frontend
    networks:
      - shared

networks:
  shared:
    external: true

volumes:
  frontend_node_modules: {}
  blog_node_modules: {}
  evsite_node_modules: {}
  library_node_modules: {}
```

And here's the nginx conf file:

```
events {}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://frontend:3001;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /blog {
      proxy_pass http://frontend:3002;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  }
}
```

The reason I can't figure out what's going wrong is because nginx seems to work fine for the 'ev-site' that is hosted at "/" from http://frontend:3001/ without any issues, but the blog that's running at http://frontend:3002/ refuses to connect to the backend. Both ev-site and blog are fetching from the backend. Since it works outside of docker and without nginx, I think this is due to my nginx config but I've been looking at this for a day and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Happy to provide any other code snippet if needed, thanks

EDIT:
To put another spin on this: my backend is actually already deployed on a digitalocean droplet. Using the IP of the deployed server and still running the frontend on my localhost the blog site is able to fetch

Comment: I'm speculating here, but each service in you docker-compose.yml can be treated as a different machine, but without docker they are all on the same machine. So I think your problem is the default postgreSQL settings. check that `pg_hba.conf` is not only bound to localhost (which would only work on the same machine) and I also think `listen_addresses` in [postgresql.conf](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/misc/postgresql.conf.sample) is bound to localhost by default.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no issue with the database. The backend is connected to postgres correctly. It's the connection between backend and frontend I'm having the problem with. The 'ev-site' is fetching from the backend and backend is returning data from the db no problem

Comment: ok, sorry, I need to work on my reading comprehension then!